# How can I display a Thankyou page after user downloads file?

Tags: php, html

I am using this little pusher php file to download an 'exe' file for the user to save when they fill-out a form.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

with this method there is no link to the online $file location for someone to follow but for some reason I cannot display a thank you page after or even immediately before the code is executed.

I've tried header( "Location: $thankyouurl" );  immediately after the above code, but nothing is ever displayed and I've tried echoing the html source of the thank you page just prior to running the above code, but that causes the exe file to be downloaded to the web page actually crashing the browser.

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Point the user directly to a static page that displays your thank you message. Then, use JavaScript to set the `window.location` to your download script.

If your download page's headers are set up correctly, the browser will start downloading the file, while your user is reading your thank you message.

Make sure to display a direct download link in case the user has JavaScript disabled.

## Example:

**index.php**

```
<a href="thankyou.php">Click here to download.</a>
```

**thankyou.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startDownload() {
            window.location = "/download.php";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="startDownload();">
    <h1>Thank you!</h1>
    <p>Your download will start in a moment. If it doesn't, use this <a href="download.php">direct link.</a></p>
</body>
```

**download.php**

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

## Update

In order to pass data from `index.php` on to the download script, you could use `GET` variables. The link to the `thankyou.php` page would become `thankyou.php?download=12` where download is an ID for you to grab the correct file. You would then pass that variable on to your download script by echoing it out in your markup like so:

**index.php**

```
<a href="thankyou.php?download=12">Click here to download.</a>
```

**thankyou.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startDownload() {
            window.location = "/download.php?file=<?=$_GET['download']?>";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="startDownload();">
    <h1>Thank you!</h1>
    <p>Your download will start in a moment. If it doesn't, use this <a href="download.php?file=<?=$_GET['download']?>">direct link.</a></p>
</body>
```

You'd then grab the value in your download script and handle it any way you like.

Comment: I think this is it.  But now how do I pass the value of $file to download.php.  In my original version I used form posting and multiple values to create the value for $file and the values were pseudo passed by the downloader file being 'included'.   I've combined you idea with mine by the form ost calling the initialing php file that echos a new version of the thatnk you page with the startedownload java script in the header.  Now I can;t see how to pass the $file value from the js to the php file.

Comment: Thank you for the corroboration.  I was just about to try that.

Comment: The thankyou page is displayed and the hard link works but the startdownload function seems to do nothing.

Comment: Perfect  this IS it.   Since I used an echo function to create the ThankYou page I didn't need the $_Get  my script call looked some thing like             <script type="text/javascript">
      function startDownload() {
            window.location = "dwnldtrial.php?file='.$file.'";
        }
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure on this, would a...

```
header('Location: thanks_page.php');
```

...not work,. if placed after the readfile()? Unsure on it really, only my thoughts!

Comment: Just wondering, another option may be to include the header('Location: ....'); before the readfile() as the script could continue to be run even after the header has loaded the thanks page, just an option, not 100% sure but worth a try? Possibly before the ob_clean(); also.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the "download page" with an "windows.open( 'url to download file' )"

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openDownload()
    {
        window.open( "http://domain.com/download.php?file=file.pdf" );
        window.location = "http://domain.com/thanks.php";
    }
</script>
```

Opening a window that directly download a file, this will be automatically closed when you chose save or cancel and then, the "parent" window redirect to thanks page.

Answer (score 0):

Using your original method, add `header('location: thank-you-page.php');` to the end, along with an exit, as shown here:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);

header('location: thank-you-page.php');
exit;
```

Comment: The Thankyou page is an html and it seems anything after the readfile just doesn't happen.

Comment: If you're wanting to force the file to download, why are you using `readfile`?